# CKEditor angular2 drag and drop

Tags: angular, ckeditor

When i see the documentation of CKEditor http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/draganddrop.html . So how to access the CKeditor instance in angular2 to access the editors drag and drop feature. I tried creating a instance of the ckeditor component in constructor but that didn't work

Comment: Please demonstrate what you tried and where you failed to do ?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* Please include your expected results, your attempted solutions, and why they didn't work. Please see the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details.